# SQL Dependency missing command text

Tags: sql-server, azure-application-insights

I have a problem with Application Insights on Azure App Service. The problem is that SQL Dependencies in Command property is not showing the generated SQL.

I can only see `<server_name> | <database_name>`, whereas in the other app I can see the whole query.

The only differences between them are:

1. Application Insights SDK version: 1.3 (where it works) vs newest (2.1.0)
2. App service plan: Premium P2 (where it works) vs Standard S1
3. The app service where it works was created few months earlier, but it is still new app service, not classic one.

I am not able to install AppInsights v1.3 (Azure installs newest version) nor easily change app service plan for app service where it is not working.

Why is this behaving differently?  How can I see all of the generated SQL on the newest installation?

EDIT:
I'm adding Insights packages installed on WebApp (from packages.config):

```
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.JavaScript" version="0.15.0-build58334" targetFramework="net46" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.TelemetryChannel" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
```

Comment: related, but probably not exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33101685/how-can-i-log-the-sql-query-to-ai?rq=1

Comment: You're right - related, but that one is about on-premise installation, where you have access to IIS, but my App is Azure App Service and I cannot just install Status Monitor.

Answer (score 1):

for the 2.x sdks, you need to install status monitor to collect sql statements.

Presuming Azure from your question, this extension will install status monitor: http://www.siteextensions.net/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites/

More info: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-asp-net-dependencies/

Comment: Thanks for reply. I installed Application Insights 2.1.3 extension before asking this question but it didn't help. I tried find something in documentation but it only tells that I have to install Status Monitor. It is clear how to install it in IIS (local or on VM), but it is AppService and I don't have access. I edited my post and added packages which are installed in WebApp.